# Difficult complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I found this integral awfully simple, but then with the obtained bounds, I thought it must be more difficult than this, and I have done some mistake.

The integral is $$\int_{\gamma}\text{sin}(z^3)+e^{z{^2}}\text{d}z,$$ where $\gamma:[0,\pi]\to\mathbb{C}$ is given by $$\gamma(t):=\text{sin}\,t+i\arctan( t^4-\pi t^3).$$

If you insert the upper and lower bounds of *t* in $\gamma$, you get $0$ for both. So the integral turns into the strange integral

$$\int_{0}^0\text{sin}(t^3)+e^{t{^2}}\,\text{d}t,$$ which must be zero? But this is an awkward integral and result.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Here $\gamma(t)$ is a simple, closed curve in the complex plane. There is a very powerful theorem that helps evaluate integrals like this. Do you know the theorem I'm referring to?

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem in Calculus

Comment: I was thinking of Cauchy's theorem. It is not just the fundamental theorem of calculus, but in a way it is the complex analog to the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: You can add a second answer to this question. I will thumb it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\sin(z^3)+e^{z^2}$ is an entire function, it has an antiderivative, and therefore its integral along *any* loop is $0$.

Comment: Thanks Jose, you are great!!